# Insert into mysql database

Tags: c#

I'm trying to insert a value into the databse like this:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mail('" + s2[0] + "') values" + "('" + s2[1] + "')";
```

s2[0] contains the name of the field while s2[1] contains the value.
I want to mention that the string contained in s2[0] matches exactly the name of the field from the table.

What seems to be the problem?

PS: i'd also like to know that exception to throw if the table doesn't have a field to match s2[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove extra ' from the string after mail

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mail(" + s2[0] + ") values" + "('" + s2[1] + "')";
```

try to use sql command with the [sqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to quote the name of the field with apostrophies. Don't do that - it's not a value, it's part of the SQL itself. You're also missing a space between "values" and the opening parenthesis of the values collection. That may or may not cause a problem - not sure. For example, currently your insertion might be something like:

```
INSERT INTO mail('name') values('jon')
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO mail(name) values ('jon')
```

You should also use a parameterised query to avoid SQL injection attacks. That's hard to do for the field name, but you should definitely do it for the value. Hopefully the field name isn't coming from a user to start with though.